# MongoDB array sort not working in CosmoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

**UPDATE**

The CosmoDB team confirmed that there is an issue on their said and they are already working on a fix.

More info in the comment section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

we are planning to migrate to CosmoDB but we found an issue with the $sort command.
In our current MongoDB server running this query:

```
db.getCollection('Product').find({ 
"ProductTypeId" : ObjectId("5913546b1ba88338e4347641"), 
"SubtypeIngredients" : "5949852c1ba88344d0facbf5"
})
.skip(0).sort({ "IngredientRanks.2.Rank" : 1 }).limit(1)
```

We get some results but when running the same query in CosmoDB we don't get any results.

**if I remove the sort command from the query, I get results from CosmoDB**

The data in the collection is the same in our local db and CosmoDB.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Update:**

Here is an screenshot of the actual query showing the issue.

[image]

Comment: I honestly doubt that your data is the same. Try running a .count() and see if the numbers match up first. Sorting does not filter your data and neither does an empty filter document...

Comment: @dnickless I've attached some screenshoots with the queries and the results.

Comment: I tend to be in general agreement with the answer just added, which I know does not "really answer" but it does address the important point. CosmosDB is NOT MongoDB, but merely "claims" to be wire protocol compatible in that drivers written for MongoDB should be able to connect and execute queries. But this does not change that it is in fact "an entirely different thing". So the general recommendation is 1. If you want to use CosmosDB then use it's "own" native API, and not a compatibility claim. 2. If you want code written to MongoDB API to work "as designed", then use MongoDB instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn I agree with you that I should use CosmoDB "own" API. But since we already have an app that is running with MongoDB and CosmoDB claims that you can migrate your data, switch your connection string and use the same driver, we wanted to give it a try as we don't want to deploy a VM in azure with a Mongo Server.

Comment: I believe the overall point here "claim" is not the same as "actually does". Unfortunately the "claims" of inter-operable skirt quite misleadingly on the side of "just the same". An "Apple" is not an "Orange", no matter if someone claims they have one that tastes just the same. Still not an "Orange".

Comment: Have you tried running the query without the useless and incorrectly positioned `skip(0)`? Also, what happens when you drop the filter condition and only use `sort()`? I would expect that at least all basic functionality (sorting counts as one of them for me) works identically on both systems.

Comment: Actually, you got the answer yourself in the meantime on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction - the Cosmos DB team seem to have confirmed that there is a problem which is being worked on.

Comment: Yes I've just saw the reply from MS which is great news!

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific guarantee that CosmoDB supports all the operators and functions of MongoDB, particularly non-trivial use of the API (like chaining `sort`, `skip` , etc.).   This extends to index optimization and selection as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I red this in CosmoDM site: "MongoDB compatibility: You can use your existing MongoDB expertise, application code, and tooling. You can develop applications using MongoDB and deploy them to production using the fully managed globally distributed Cosmos DB service." I was not hopping that everything worked as it was MongoDB, but since we are not using any "advance" feature we wanted to give it a try... It is a shame that because of this simple sort we are not able to migrate to CosmoDB :(

Comment: Don't be shy about giving it the +1 to help others.  ;-)

Comment: I got an answer from MS here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction. They said that it is an issue that they are already fixing.

Comment: @JorgeRamosEguinoa here i am in January of 2019 and it still doesn't work. what did you guys end up doing if you don't mind me askng? i tried a raw query with `$orderBy` instead of `sort()` and it doesn't work either. why even use a database if it has no way to sort? kind of stupid.

Comment: No problem at all! We ended up working with the official MongoDB service (Atlas) hosted in Azure as this feature was a must for us. As of today I did not hear back from support and to be honest I don't think they will ever fix this. For me CosmoDB was a really disappointment because of the pricing and the lack of basic features as these.

Comment: April/2020 and I'm strugglig with sorting collection items by a string field in Cosmos DB :-/

Answer (score -1):

This is what is mentioned in the cosmosdb website

[image]